# Varbinary(20) joins performing poorly

Tags: performance, sql-server-2014

I have a performance problem, I have a stage fact column with approximately 2mil records with ~40 dimensions business keys columns which are sha1 hashes - varbinary(20). My query looks like this:

```
select isnull(dim1.surkey,0)
      ,isnull(dim2.surkey,0)
 -- 40 surrogate keys here
 -- some measures
from stage_fact sf
left join dim1 on sf.dim1businesskey = dim1.businesskey
left join dim2 on sf.dim2businesskey = dim2.businesskey
-- 40 joins here
```

This while having about 2 milion test data - takes about 8minutes. On production it could have about 10 milions data every month. This is way to slow for our needs.

Any way on how to improve it ?

There are alredy nonclustered indexes in each dimension table containing surrogate key and business key.

I tried to put all of the businesskey columns in a columnstore index but this is not helping. Also I tried to add 40 nonclustered indexes on each of the businesskey columns in stage_fact - this takes about 2 minutes but still does not help to the performance (optimizer performs table scan anyway).

I will be grateful for any ideas on improving this query.

Best regards,

EDIT:
Query execution plan here:
[Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJs1iSAbX)

Comment: I added the plan. Thanks.

Comment: The most obvious is the table scan at the end. We can't see the statement, so I'm not sure what table this is for. If you look at the very end of that plan, there is a table scan of 15 million rows to do the join. That's 15% of your query cost right there. Adding an index here to the correct column for the join will result in an index scan and be quicker. Can you post the entire query? Function calls hurt, obviously (like `ISNULL`)